# How can I change network connection of my vmware vms through vim cmd through putty

Tags: ssh, vmware

I have an ovh-hosted dedicated VMWare server I connect to through vShpere.

I can manually change the network interfaces of all virtual machines but I need to do this through ssh using putty so that I can automate the process later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I found the answer.

After connecting to the server through ssh

1. Run the command ***vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms*** to get all the machines present.
   Note the **VMID** of the machine whose network interface you want to change.
2. Power off the machine by running the command ***vim-cmd vmsvc/power.off "VMID"***.
3. Now go to the folder where .vmx file of the machine is located.
4. Using **vi** editor edit the .vmx file to change the content on line containing the text **"ethernet0.networkName= '*any_network_name*'"** to the network you want.
   Save and exit the editor.
5. Now power on the machine by running the command ***vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on "VMID"***.

Network interface must be changed now.